# google displays my website wrong in results of search

Tags: html, search

I just realized of this. 
I search my website in google, and in results of search, google displays my website, **but with strange chars where must be accent words**
So, I added within the tag  of my index, a new tag meta, like this:

```
<meta charset="iso-8859-1" />
```

What do you think? Could this meta solve my problem?
Regards, Daniel

EDIT:
I have in my index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>" >
```

Is a website made with Joomla.

Comment: This needs more information. What do the characters in Google look like? What encoding is your site in?

Comment: To give you batter answer provide us url example or an serp keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is sent with HTTP headers that indicate the content as UTF-8 encoded. No `meta` tag can override this, by HTML specs, but it is possible that Google gets confused, especially since the page already has a `meta` tag that specifies UTF-8. So remove `<meta charset="iso-8859-1" />`.

The actual content seems to be mostly UTF-8 encoded, but some comments in JavaScript code as well as some HTML comments are ISO-8859-1 encoded. The reason is probably that they were copied from somewhere in that encoding. Fix this, or (for testing at least) remove the comments. Although comments are functionally ignored by search robots, it is possible that they get confused.

(They have to read all the characters, and since ISO-8859-1 encoded character data is often not valid in UTF-8 data at all, Google might “second-guess” the encoding in some contexts.)

Comment: Hi Jukka, thanks very much for your answer. I don't know if I understood well, but you have looked the comments I did in the javascript code (my intencion is explain the code, for future people who can access this code, and don't understand at first time). You advise me to remove these comments, right? Regards.

Comment: I dit you advised me: fixed the comments in the code, and removed the <meta charset="iso-8859-1" /> ... I imagine that I have to wait some days in order to google robots visit my website, right? Best regards.

Comment: Right, the comments are OK as long as they have characters correctly encoded. I’m not sure if the fix resolves the issue, but let’s hope it does. But it may take longer than just some days. It might be possible to speed it up, see http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1352276 (I already used the “Crawl URL” there).

Comment: Hi again Jukka. After doing you told me (including use the crawl url) I see my site well in results of search. Thanks very much for your help! Daniel